# How to set laravel 10's default login and register option in another page rather than welcome.blade.php

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, laravel-10

How to set laravel 10's default login and register option in another page rather than welcome.blade.php

I've tried changing the default welcome.blade.php into my landing page html but login and register option isn't displaying there!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Want you login and register links in your own page? You need to add links. In file welcome.blade.php see the code starting with `@if (Route::has('login'))`